# Optimization of Regular Expression to match numbers bigger or equal to 50

Tags: regex

I want to check if a number is 50 or more using a regular expression. This in itself is no problem but the number field has another regex checking the format of the entered number.

The number will be in the continental format: 123.456,78 (a dot between groups of three digits and always a comma with 2 digits at the end)

Examples:

```
100.000,00
50.000,00
50,00
34,34
etc.
```

I want to capture numbers which are 50 or more. So from the four examples above the first three should be matched.

I've come up with this rather complicated one and am wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

```
^(\d{1,3}[.]|[5-9][0-9]|\d{3}|[.]\d{1,3})*[,]\d{2}$
```

**EDIT**

I want to match continental numbers here. The numbers have this format due to internal regulations and specify a price. 
Example: 1000 EUR would be written as 1.000,00 EUR
50000 as 50.000,00 and so on.

Comment: what does the value 123.456,78 signify ?

Comment: @marvel308 123 thousand 456 and 78 hundedth. Not all people in the world use the system you have got at school.

Comment: A dot between three numbers??? What do you want to say? Nothing can happen between three objects! And don't mix numbers and digits, too.

Comment: Your example won't work, it is too free: https://regex101.com/r/1ijc3f/7

Comment: Optimised for what? Readability? Performance? Length? Ease of understanding?

Comment: I would find it helpful if someone would tell me why they found that the question should be downvoted. Nothing against that, but if you tell me the reason for this, then I can improve.

Comment: If, as you state, the numbers always are correctly formatted, simply `^(5\d|\d{3,}).*$` should do it. [Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6ZPzLh/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

**EDIT** `^(.{3,}|[5-9]\d),\d{2}$`

It checks if:

- there 3 chars or more before the `,`
- there are 2 numbers before the `,` and the first is between 5 and 9
- and then a `,` and 2 numbers

Donno if it answer your question as it'll return true for:

- aa50,00
- 1sdf,54

But this assumes that your original string is a number in the format you expect (as it was not a requirement in your question).

**EDIT 3**

The regex below tests if the number is valid referring to the *continental format* and if it's equal or greater than 50. See [tests here](https://regex101.com/r/llCD3j/2).

Regex: `^((([1-9]\d{0,2}\.)(\d{3}\.){0,}\d{3})|([1-9]\d{2})|([5-9]\d)),\d{2}$`

Explanation (d is a number):

- `([1-9]\d{0,2}\.)`: either `d.`, `dd.` or `ddd.` one time with the first `d` between 1 and 9.
- `(\d{3}\.){0,}`: `ddd.` zero or x time
- `\d{3}`: `ddd` 3 digit

These 3 parts combined match any numbers equals or greater than 1000 like: `1.000`, `22.002` or `100.000.000`.

- `([1-9]\d{2})`: any number between 100 and 999.
- `([5-9]\d))`: a number between 5 and 9 followed by a number. Matches anything between 50 and 99. 
  So it's either the one of the parts above or this one.

Then `,\d{2}$` matches the comma and the two last digits.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/1ijc3f/3 look, your regex is too strict! And don't escape \\ excessively, until you know in what surrounding it would be used.

Comment: @Gangnus I did the test using a string with Java. That's why it's escaped. Forgot to remove it. But you're right. Why is my regex too strict as in your example it matches the string as required by op? Btw thanks as I didn't know this website.

Comment: Sorry, I have given you bad tests. 51,22 or 60.00-99,99 won't match, but they must. aaa,000 and 1a4,00 shouldn't match, but they do (use '\d' instead of '.'). Also 5555,00 or aaaaaaa555555555,55. Or even (){}@#$&51,22

Comment: Actually 51,22 and 60.00-99,99 match.I know that 5555,00 will match but op didn't say he wanted to validate the number, he just asked that the regex should reject any number under 50 in a string ending with a comma and 2 digits. Checking that the string is a valid number wasn't part of the requirements that why I said that maybe the answer is not the one expected by op.

Comment: Yep, this is what I said. As long as the input number is a valid number in the continental format, my answer works (as validating the number is not part of the question)

Comment: 9.999.999,99 - is valid, and OK for your regex, but incorrect. And don't lie to ourself - the OP obviously is trying to check the format.

Comment: And please, check my regex, too!

Comment: Tbh I'm not sure you've answered to the question as op asked for an **easier** version of his own regex.

Comment: Thanks. The RegEx from your EDIT 2 looks good and will certainly work in my case.
Yes, I'm dealing with continental numbers here, sorry I did not specify this in the first place. I'll edit my question above to reflect this.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new regex (EDIT 3) as checking @slim answer, I realised that the previous regex considered `000,00` as a valid number equals or greater than 50. I've updated the tests too so you can try other numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of taste, obviously, but using a negative lookahead gives a simple solution.

```
^(?!([1-4]?\d),)[1-9](\d{1,2})?(\.\d{3})*,\d{2}\b
```

In words: starting from a boundary ignore all numbers that start with 1 digit OR 2 digits (the first being a 1,2,3 or 4), followed by a comma.

Check on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1ijc3f/17)

Comment: You take 0,78 or 9.999.999,99. Also, you have forgotten to close regex by another \b. Poor tests, I am afraid. try these https://regex101.com/r/1ijc3f/5

Comment: Thanks for the 0,78. I stand corrected: https://regex101.com/r/iF4Nu7/5. For the other issues: 9.999.999,99 is a correct example, so nothing to do there. And you don't need the closing \b except if examples are put on one line.

Comment: Why don't you do tests before publishing? https://regex101.com/r/1ijc3f/9 - you match 9.999.999,99 and 5,00. And be fair - check my regex, too

Comment: Made adaptations in original post. Except for the 9.999.999,99, which is IMHO a correct number. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Maybe. The author should correct his question to make it clear, what number are acceptable and what not. Otherwards it looks OK now.

Comment: @Gangnus _The number will be in the continental format [...] (a dot between **groups** of three digits and always a comma with 2 digits at the end)_ I think it's quite clear.

Comment: @mlambrichs You answer matches `000,00`

Comment: @Eselfar very observant. Can be easily fixed by replacing \d{1,3} by an explicit [1-9]([0-9]{1,2})? See: https://regex101.com/r/1ijc3f/15. Takes a bit of the simplicity of the original answer away, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah a bit more complicated than expected but op has updated his answer to specify he wants to match the format too, so it doesn't seem we can have something easy anymore. I quite like your solution.

Comment: Maybe this is even better: making explicit what you don't want: https://regex101.com/r/1ijc3f/16

Comment: The issue it that it now matches `00.000,00`. I think your previous one can be simplify a bit like that `^(?!([1-4]?\d),)[1-9](\d{1,2})?(\.\d{3})*,\d{2}\b`. Btw, why did you need the `?:` in `(?:\.\d{3})`?

Comment: @Eselfar Agreed. This one is nicer. The idea that you specify what you don't want in the negative lookahead still stands rather nicely. So you can easily reuse this pattern for any other boundary/number. And yes, there is no need for capturing, so we can get rid of the ?: Well done.

Answer (score 0):

*I have named all inner groups, for better understanding what part of number is matched by each group. After you understand how it works, change all `?P<..>` to `?:`.*

This one is for any dec number in the continental format.

```
^(?P<common_int>(?P<int>(?P<int_start>[1-9]\d{1,2}|[1-9]\d|[1-9])(?P<int_end>\.\d{3})*|0)(?!,)|(?P<dec_int_having_frac>(?P<dec_int>(?P<dec_int_start>[1-9]\d{1,2}|[1-9]\d|[1-9])(?P<dec_int_end>\.\d{3})*,)|0,|,)(?=\d))(?P<frac_from_comma>(?<=,)(?P<frac>(?P<frac_start>\d{3}\.)*(?P<frac_end>\d{1,3})))?$
```

[test](https://regex101.com/r/1ijc3f/1/)

This one is for the same with the limit `number>=50`

```
^(?P<common_int>(?P<int>(?P<int_start>[1-9]\d{1,2}|[1-9]\d|[1-9])(?P<int_end>\.\d{3})+|(?P<int_short>[1-9]\d{2}|[5-9]\d))(?!,)|(?P<dec_int_having_frac>(?P<dec_int>(?P<dec_int_start>[1-9]\d{1,2}|[1-9]\d|[1-9])(?P<dec_int_end>\.\d{3})+,)|(?P<dec_short_int>[1-9]\d{2}|[5-9]\d),)(?=\d))(?P<frac_from_comma>(?<=,)(?P<frac>(?P<frac_start>\d{3}\.)*(?P<frac_end>\d{1,3})))?$
```

[tests](https://regex101.com/r/1ijc3f/2)

If you always have the integer part under 999.999 and fractal part always 2 digits, it will be a bit more simple:

```
^(?P<dec_int_having_frac>(?P<dec_int>(?P<dec_int_start>[1-9]\d{1,2}|[1-9]\d|[1-9])(?P<dec_int_end>\.\d{3})?,)|(?P<dec_short_int>[1-9]\d{2}|[5-9]\d),)(?=\d)(?P<frac_from_comma>(?<=,)(?P<frac>(?P<frac_end>\d{1,2})))?$
```

[test](https://regex101.com/r/1ijc3f/4)

Comment: So, your solution does not accept 9.999.999,99. I think that's not intended.

Comment: That IS indended, I am understanding the question this way. Maybe, I am wrong, we all need explanations from the author of the question. Without that limit we should only change ? to *.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the number is correctly formed -- that is, that the regex isn't expected to detect that `5,0.1` is invalid, then there are a limited number of passing cases:

- ends with `\d{3}`
- ends with `[5-9]\d`
- contains `\d{3},`
- contains `[5-9]\d,`

It's not actually necessary to do anything with `\.`

The *easiest* regex is to code for each of these individually:

```
(\d{3}$|[5-9]\d$|\d{3},|[5-9]\d)
```

You *could* make it more compact and efficient by merging some of the cases:

```
(\d{3}[$,]|[5-9]\d[$,])
```

If you need to also validate the format, you will need extra complexity. I would advise against attempting to do both in a single regex.

---

*However* unless you have a very good reason for having to do this with a regex, I recommend against it. Parse the string into an integer, and compare it with 50.

Comment: Apparently your _compact_ regex match with `000,`. See [this example.](https://regex101.com/r/CQS6F0/1)

Comment: I've just realized that I have the same issue in my own solution :/

Comment: @Eselfar - oh dear, you're right. In fact both regexes match `000`. I may come back and fix it, but for now I just take it as further evidence that it's better to parse into an integer and compare it with 50.

Comment: I'm agree about that too, better to use an interger instead of using a string.